# Git branches and merging back

Tags: git, github

I've created a repository for a site i've been working on lately. Now i'm going to be duplicating the site, thus my thinking is i'll create a new branch in Git, that way I can deal with changes to that tool in particular, separately. But also merge in important changes back to the main branch.

The only thing that worries me is, say 50% of the changes need to be pushed back to the core and 50% need to be kept on this branch.

Can anyone suggest how this could be managed, as I'm unsure of whether or not you can only push back to the core branch specific changes to the secondary branch.

Hopefully you follow what i'm saying?

If not, ask for clarity.

Comment: It looks like you have two requirements for the same code base.  To me this sounds a little bit similar to copy and pasting code but in this case, done smartly.  I would recommend you take a look at the code and see if it can be refactored in such away that you have a Core library that is then used by these two sites.  I have no doubt there will be SOME code duplication, but I think that would be easier to manage than what you are suggesting here.

Comment: Also take a look at git cherry-pick, using that, you can select which commits should be applied on the second branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be no problem at all. Lets assume you have repo A (the first repo) with a master branch (or perhaps you want to name it core). Lets assume that A is also a bare repo (so you can push up changes to it).

Just clone A into a new repo B:

```
git clone A B
cd B
git checkout -b B-stuff
```

Add stuff to B-stuff branch as you see fit. When you notice you have a change that should be in core, just check out the master branch, commit there and push:

```
git checkout master
.. changes
git commit -am 'foo'
git push origin master
```

Comment: Forgive me if i'm wrong, but just so i'm following you properly, I've cloned the original repository Cloning into msplugin... then i've just cd'd inside it and ran the git checkout -b B-stuff command. Your saying that it should be as easy as just switching back to the master and committing changes, if I want to push the changes to the so called 'core' else just use the branch.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying :)

Comment: Sweet. Kinda what I was thinking before making this post, easy enough :-) thanks alot.